# How to "execute" onCreate method when activity in tabLayout is selected?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, oncreate

I have two activities in tab layout. In first activity I'm adding elements to listview and in second activity, the listview is displayed. So the problem is that after I'm done adding elements to listview in first activity, the listview can't be seen on the second activity until I restart the whole application.

I'm guessing this happens because I'm creating listview inside of onCreate method, and onCreate method is executed only when the activity is completely destroyed and re-created. But since this is a tabLayout, the onCreate is already executed before I even start adding elements to listView.

So my question is: How do I make the activity execute onCreate everytime it is clicked in tabLayout? Or is maybe there another way, to put listView outside onCreate and make it refresh or something?

This is the code inside onCreate, if it helps:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.mainListView);
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, recordedFilesArray);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView));
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Everything works perfect, except for the fact that I need to restart the app for the listview to update.

Comment: "I have two activities in tab layout" -- this has been deprecated for ~2.5 years. Please consider using modern replacements, such as `FragmentTabHost`, `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator, or action bar tabs.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've only started android/java programming about 2-3 months back. So I don't really know any better. Could you maybe provide me with some newbie friendly tutorials for those other options? I'll google for them myself, but just asking since you already mentioned :)

Comment: `FragmentTabHost` has a full sample [in its JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html). Action bar tabs are covered [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), as is [the use of `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). I'm sure that there are independent tutorials on the action bar tabs and `ViewPager` options, and they are covered in books as well. `FragmentTabHost` is probably the least popular of the 3, though it's closest to your current code.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used your advice and started implementing FragmentTabHost, but I ran into some difficulties. I opened a new question, since I'm stuck. I hope I'm not asking too much. [this is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137121/creating-fragmenttabhost-causing-some-trouble)

Comment: Saw that and already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone gave me a better solution now (check comments) but I'll still answer my own question. I did some more research and found something.

It's quite simple. When creating intent for the tab, you just need to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and it works.

Like this:

```
Intent libraryIntent = new Intent(this, RecordedLibrary.class);
libraryIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```