# Creating FragmentTabHost causing some trouble

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

So I'm developing an app and until now, I was using ordinary tab layout with two activities. Now someone told me that it's much better to do it usning FragmentTabHost. So I've been reading some [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html) and this is what I came up with so far:

MainActivity_Fragment:

```
public class MainActivity_Fragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    }

}
```

RecordedLibrary_Fragment:

```
public class RecordedLibrary_Fragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_recorded_library, container, false);
    }
}
```

TabLayout activity:

```
public class TabLayout extends FragmentActivity {

//GLOBAL VARIABLES///////////////
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_layout);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), r.id....); // <-- problem here

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Recording").setIndicator("Recording"),
            MainActivity_Fragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Library").setIndicator("Library"),
            RecordedLibrary_Fragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

Now this is where I am stuck. There are a few things that aren't explained in the docs. So I have two questions.

This line in the docs:

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
```

Where did they get R.id.realtabcontent ?

And another thing that isn't explained; how should the xml of the tab activity look?

My current tab layout xml:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the tab layout xml is still from the old tab layout. Do I need to adjust it to FragmentTabLayout or is it good this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now someone told me that it's much better to do it usning FragmentTabHost.

Well, I *did* [say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133136/how-to-execute-oncreate-method-when-activity-in-tablayout-is-selected#comment26555020_18133136) "`FragmentTabHost` is probably the least popular of the 3, though it's closest to your current code."

> Where did they get R.id.realtabcontent ?

That's the ID of a widget in a layout. Specifically it would be in `R.layout.fragment_tabs`, which the documentation neglects to show.

Fortunately, this appears to be from the support package samples, and that layout can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/2d52182dfac91014c2975a1bb1afd99a3b14b4e9/samples/Support4Demos/res/layout/fragment_tabs.xml), with the definition at the time of this writing as:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

> And another thing that isn't explained; how should the xml of the tab activity look?

See above.

> Do I need to adjust it to FragmentTabLayout or is it good this way?

Well, if nothing else, you will need to replace `TabHost` with `FragmentTabHost`.

But, frankly, `FragmentTabHost` is worse off, documentation-wise, than I was remembering when I commented on your earlier question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. FragmentTabHost seems to work fine now, but I have one more question. Buttons, listviews and everything that I have in those fragments aren't working now. Like I just copied the layout, but left out all the methods etc. any idea where I went wrong? I watched some tutorials on how to create fragments but I was never told that I'll also have to copy the code

Comment: @Matthew: Generally speaking, fragments manage their own widgets. You were attempting to use `TabActivity` with nested activities. Those nested activities should be converted to fragments. That will mean not only converting those activities' layouts to be used by fragments, but all code in support of the widgets in those layouts would move along with the layouts.

Comment: I did do that, I converted MainActivity.java and RecordedLibrary.java to fragments (you can see it in my original post)

Comment: @Matthew: Then I have no idea what you mean by "left out all the methods".

Comment: The tabs are showing, I can switch between fragments, but nothing in the app is working. Buttons that are supposed to do something, do nothing when they're clicked and the library activity is supposed to show a listview, but it is empty. Basically it feels like it's just a layout, no code.

Comment: @Matthew: "I converted MainActivity.java and RecordedLibrary.java to fragments" -- and you will notice that those fragments do absolutely nothing with their widgets. All they do is load their layouts. Hence, you are getting exactly what you wrote. If you want widgets to respond to events, you need to hook up event listeners. If you did that in your earlier activities, that code needs to be moved to these fragments.

Comment: So what I need to do now is basically copy the code I wrote in MainActivity.java to MainActivity_Fragment.java. I'm new to android programming as you can see so I do a lot of mistakes like this, I hope to get better soon :) I thought that creating a fragment will "inherit" the code, but I can now understand and see that I was very wrong. Thank you for your help mate! I'm still pretty sure I'll just create Swipe Views at the end of the day.

Comment: @Matthew: "So what I need to do now is basically copy the code I wrote in MainActivity.java to MainActivity_Fragment.java" -- well, I can't speak to *all*, as I don't know what was in the activity. However, if there was functionality from the activity you want the fragment to do, you'll need to copy it over. "I thought that creating a fragment will "inherit" the code" -- no, there's no Java inheritance from your old fragment going on here.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and explaining again, take care mate :)

Comment: @CommonsWare in `FragmentTabHost` why the `FrameLayout` with id tabcontent is there? I know its off topic but can you please help i'm confused!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare n.p problem thanks :) i have also posted the same question on Android Developer groups on Google.